# Johnny Cache with template caching

Tags: django, caching, django-johnny-cache

I'm setting up Johnny Cache alongside template caching using Django 1.4. Our current setup looks like this:

```
# Django Cache
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '192.168.100.1:11211',
    }
}

# JohnnyCache
JOHNNY_CACHE_BACKEND = "memcached://192.168.100.1:11211/"
MAN_IN_BLACKLIST = ('django_session',...)
```

JOHNNY_CACHE_BACKEND has been deprecated, so we need to move johnny setting inside our caches dictionary. [Per the documenataion](http://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/index.html#usage), this seems easy enough. But, what happens to our template caching? Do these settings live alongside each other, like this?

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '192.168.100.1:11211',
    }
    'default' : dict(
        BACKEND = 'johnny.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        LOCATION = ['192.168.100.1:11211'],
        JOHNNY_CACHE = True,
    )
}
```

Or is johnny.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache a replacement for django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache, in which case we should just have this:

```
CACHES = {
    'default' : dict(
        BACKEND = 'johnny.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        LOCATION = ['192.168.100.1:11211'],
        JOHNNY_CACHE = True,
    )
}
```

Which would handle query and template caching. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jason Moiron ‏@jmoiron (creator of Johnny Cache) via Twitter:

> it's a straight replacement, only diff is its treatment of 0 (johnny's makes 0 = inf, django's makes 0 be instant timeout)